# how to make counter database smaller in size?

Tags: mysql, counter

I have website with counter and each time some person enters website new row is added. This thing makes database great in size. actually not so great, it is 3 mb. But Godaddy loads that website very slow. I have emptied counter table and website is loading very rapidly now. Is there any way to store counter or to make it more rapid?

Comment: why you need to add a new row ??  you just increase the counter..

Comment: i want to know which url he looks, what is his ip. i need his url to know which part of website is most popular and i need ip to know how many users, not clicks has website

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with a field `counter`, insert a row with value 0 at the beginning and just increment it on every visit. You can have another field with date to get counter for different dates.

```
SELECT counter FROM websiteviews WHERE date = '2016-01-05'
```

If a counter found

```
UPDATE websiteviews SET counter = counter+ 1 WHERE date = '2016-01-05'
```

Otherwise insert new row.

```
INSERT INTO websiteviews (date,counter) VALUES ('2016-01-05',1)
```

Comment: so how to know the number of hits today, yesterday ?

Comment: @user3569967 add a date field then. but even that, it's still a bad design.

Comment: so can u tell me kindly how to make counter with minimal size, but which can show me hits by days, hits by pages, count of ip's as well

Comment: Ok. Then have another field with date. See my edit above. You can add more fields this way for your other purposes. But remember that the more fields you add the more rows it will need for additional varieties.